# How to change intellij font size globally?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm try to decrease the font size of my code and the workbench menus. Doing it by File > Settings > Editor > Font only changes the font size in the code editor. Is there way to do this for the whole IDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 `Font` settings in Jetbrains.

1. To set the global scale, Open `Appearance & Behavior` > `Appearance`, enable the checkbox `Use custom font:` and then increase the `Size`
2. `Editor` > `Font` is only for the editor, so menus are not affected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

short cut may be you can us control button + keyboard wheel OR ctlr+ + or - button . That works in most case

Comment: I tried this but this only affects the code editor. Not the workbench.

Comment: Have you tried ctlr+ + or - button?

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and you're looking to switch from using intelliJ on laptop and desktop monitors, you can save different profiles to change font-sizes so you can quickly swap between them (at least for the editor):

[image: IntelliJ Editor Font Profiles]